# Can't display Selected Item in ItemSelector EXTJS 3

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, extjs, asp-classic

I'm develop ASP prorject Using extjs in the view. I have problem Using ItemSelector in EXTJS.

this is my code:

```
var isForm = new Ext.Panel({
    fieldLabel: 'Role',
    width: 700,
    bodyStyle: 'padding:10px;',
    store: GroupStore,
    //renderTo: 'itemselector',
    items: [        
    {
        xtype: 'itemselector',
        name: 'itemselector',
        fieldLabel: 'ItemSelector',
        imagePath: '../../ExtResources/ux/images/',
        multiselects: [{
            legend: 'Available',
            width: 250,
            height: 200,
            store: GroupStore,
            displayField: 'groupName',
            valueField: 'groupID'
        }
        , {
            legend: 'Selected',
            width: 250,
            height: 200,
            store: [['','']]
        }]
    }]
});
```

and this is my store:

```
var GroupStore = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
    remoteSort: true,
    root: 'data',
    //autoLoad: loadStore2,
    autoLoad: true,
    totalProperty: 'totalCount',
    idProperty: 'groupID',
    fields: [{
        name: 'groupID'
    }, {
        name: 'groupName'
    }],
    proxy: new Ext.data.HttpProxy({
        //url: 'InputUserLoadHandler.ashx?get=groups&comp=HSO'
        url: 'InputUserLoadHandler.ashx?get=groups'
    })
});
```

at the 'Selected' column cant display the Item which already selected.
I ever try using my store in the 'available' column and 'selected' but the result is the item already displayed on the both of side.

[this](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/multiselect/multiselect-demo.html) is the reffrence my ItemSelector
Please give me the solution to solve this problem...

Answer (score 0):

You set the store property of the form. It's incorrect. Try to set store in your itemselector.

Comment: Where should i put the store? when i put it into items it was error countered. the Messages is "object is null"

can you tell me where should i put it? thanks innerJL

Comment: could you post your example somewhere? at jsfiddle for example? It's really hard to tell just by code. You could replace your ajax data with simple data arrays for example.

Comment: is possible using Json? coz in my poject not using array but using Json. Thanks for your answer innerJL

Answer (score 0):

I was reload data from database, my project using Json to buffer data. The format data of companyStore like this:

```
{ "totalCount":"4", "data":[
  {
    "groupID": 1,
    "groupName": "Receiving"
  },
  {
    "groupID": 2,
    "groupName": "Checking"
  },
  {
    "groupID": 3,
    "groupName": "Shipment & Packing"
  },
  {
    "groupID": 4,
    "groupName": "Display Stock"
  }
] }
```

is it possible to use ItemSelector? in the sencha example using array.